# Parâmetro embutido na action do form não é passado via GET

Tags: html, querystring, get

Tenho o seguinte código HTML, e na action seto o endereço obedecendo a minha query string:

```html
<form name="searchCard" class="serachCard" method="get" action="painel.php?spv=nav/buscarCard">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pesquisar:</legend>
        <span>Buscar:</span>
        <input type="text" name="consulta" />
        <input type="submit" name="" class="btnSearch" value="Buscar" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

E realizo o submit no form (esperando que ele vá para a pagina indicada no action e leve em GET o valor "azul" digitado no form):

[image: submit on form]

Mas o que acontece é que ele não leva o parâmetro `spv` que fazia parte da query string no action, e fica na home do projeto (painel.php).

[image: Erro]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Quando possível poste o código e não a imagem dele, alguns proxys podem bloquear ela.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há um problema conceitual no código. Vejamos as opções para submissão de formulários HTML:

### POST

```html
<form method="post" action="painel.php">
```

Os valores dos campos do formulário são enviados no corpo da requisição. A URL fica "livre" para você colocar parâmetros adicionais, mas cuidado para não usar os mesmos nomes de campos do formulário.

### GET

```html
<form method="get" action="painel.php">
```

Os valores dos campos são concatenados na URL:

- `painel.php?campo1=valor1&campo2=valor2`

O corpo da requisição vai vazio e parâmetros colocados "manualmente" no action são perdidos. Isso está de acordo com a [especificação do HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4).

### Solução para incluir parâmetros adicionais em formulários GET

Campos ocultos (*hidden*):

```html
<input type="hidden" name="campo" value="valor"/>
```

### Limitações do método GET

Não é recomendável usar URLs muito grandes, pois isso pode causar erros. Por exemplo, o Internet Explorer suporta apenas 2048 caracteres na URL. O servidor HTTP Apache possui um limite de 4000. Veja mais detalhes sobre limitações em navegadores e servidores HTTP [neste link](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html). Um limite "seguro" apontados por alguns é limitar a URL em até 2000 caracteres.

Deve-se tomar cuidado quando há muitos campos em formulários que usam o método `GET`, pois rapidamente se alcança um tamanho grande.

Answer (score 6):

Se entendi bem, o seu problema é que o parâmetro `spv` não está sendo passado, certo? Eu sugiro colocar ele em uma entrada escondida (*hidden input*):

```html
<form method="get" action="painel.php>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="spv" value="nav/buscaCard" /> 
        ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: dessa forma deu certo! Obrigado... Só o barra passado no valor do input hidden que ficou assim "spv=nav%2FbuscaCard&consulta=azul". Mas enfim deu certo acho que deva ser algo relacionado ao charset! Vlw

Comment: @Luitame Disponha, e não se esqueça que você pode marcar uma resposta como aceita se ela resolve o seu problema. Quanto à barra, isso é normal - ela simplesmente foi "escapada" para ser corretamente passada na URL. O seu código do servidor (php) vai receber uma `/` corretamente, como é esperado.

Answer (score 5):

Na sua action deixa apenas o nome do arquivo.

```php
<form method="get" action="painel.php">
```

e no php verifique se o valor foi definido e contem algo.

```php
if(isset($_GET['consulta']) && !empty($_GET['consulta'])){
  echo 'valor preenchido';
}else{
  echo 'valor vazio';
}
```